# Sub Query take too much time to get rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find some records based on the tags they have. In order to find out which tags a record has I add them to the result using a subquery. To find out which results should be returned I added a having statement at the end of the query. But something tells me this is not the best way. Is there any other way to do it?

Here is the query that takes too much time to execute.

```
SELECT c.id,c.currentBalance, 
(SELECT running_balance from vrCorporateLedger WHERE company_id=c.id 
ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1) AS ledgerBalance 
FROM company AS c 
WHERE c.vrCorporate='YES' 
AND c.deleted_at IS NULL 
HAVING currentBalance > ledgerBalance
```

Comment: Can we see your query execution plan?

Comment: I would definitely get rid of that subquery (and therefore the order by), and just left join vrCorporateLedger into company.

Comment: Doe the query is fast if HAVING condition is removed?

Comment: How is this possible to get only one row from the vrCorporateLedger table by using Left join?

Comment: @Akina No Subquery gets the query slow.

Comment: If so then rename your topic. And follow @AleixCC's advice.

Comment: Do you have company_id indexed on vrCorporateLedger ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT c.id,c.currentBalance, 
vrcl.running_balance ledgerBalance 
FROM company AS c 
INNER JOIN vrCorporateLedger vrcl 
ON vrcl.id = c.company_id
WHERE c.vrCorporate='YES' 
AND c.deleted_at IS NULL 
AND currentBalance > vrcl.running_balance
```

Comment: INNER JOIN can be tricky here, you don't know the relation between both tables and the OP has not defined the question well enough to assume that this kind of join is needed/preferred.

Comment: I was going off his subquery logic - isn't that the equivalent to what INNER join would do in my query?